# how to find all first indexes in the string?

Tags: java

I am use this source:

```
String fulltext = "I would like to create a book reader  have create, create ";

String subtext = "create";
int i = fulltext.indexOf(subtext);
```

but I find only the first index, how to find all first indexes in the string ? (in this case three index)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you've found the first index, use the overloaded version of [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) that receives the start index as a second parameter:

> `public int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)` Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character, starting the search at the specified index.

Keep doing that until `indexOf` returns `-1`, indicating that there are no more matches to be found.

Answer (score 4):

Use the version of indexOf that accepts a starting position.  Use it in a loop until it doesn't find any more.

```
String fulltext = "I would like to create a book reader  have create, create ";
String subtext = "create";
int ind = 0;
do {
    int ind = fulltext.indexOf(subtext, ind);
    System.out.println("Index at: " + ind);
    ind += subtext.length();
} while (ind != -1);
```

Comment: this might be an endless loop ?? ist sould be `ind = fulltext.indexOf(subtext,i + subtext.length());`

Comment: always returns the first index =(

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex with Pattern and Matcher. `Matcher.find()` tries to find the next match and `Matcher.start()` will give you the start index of the match.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("create");
Matcher m = p.matcher("I would like to create a book reader  have create, create ");

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.start());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a while loop and use `indexof(String str, int fromIndex)`.

```
String fulltext = "I would like to create a book reader  have create, create ";
int i = 0;
String findString = "create";
int l = findString.length();
while(i>=0){

     i = fulltext.indexOf(findString,i+l);
     //store i to an array or other collection of your choice
 }
```

Comment: this might be an endless loop ?? ist sould be `i = fulltext.indexOf("create",i + "create".length());`

Comment: This one also returns the wrong answer.  Hint:  Your algorithm should account for the -1.

Comment: @james.garriss oh I see, please note that those are just samples to illustrate how `indexOf` works, and not fully working code, the point is to show that you can use it starting from a certain index in the string to find further occurrences of the substring, it is obvious that `-1` means not match found.